# Getting an 500: internal error trying to display data from +page.server.ts on SvelteKit app deployed to GitHub Pages

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, github-pages, sveltekit

I'm building a website with SvelteKit and TailwindCSS that converts a markdown file into HTML using [`markedjs`](https://github.com/markedjs/marked), and displays that on a web page. I'm deploying this site to GitHub Pages using [`gh-pages`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages). This involves producing the static SvelteKit content using [`adapter-static`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#github-pages) from Svelte. I'm running into an issue with displaying the generated HTML:

Locally, the website works, with the generated HTML displaying correctly. When I deploy to GitHub, I get an initial `500: Internal Error` on the page that's supposed to display the HTML. If I refresh the page, the content loads. Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
// +page.server.ts

import {marked} from 'marked';
import {error} from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { readFileSync } from 'node:fs';

function parseBlogpost(name: string) {
  const f = readFileSync('./src/routes/blog/hello_world.md', 'utf8');
  return marked.parse(f);
}

/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export function load({params}) {
  try {
    const content = parseBlogpost(params.slug);
    return {
      post: {
        content: content
      }
    };
  } catch(err) {
      throw error(500, {
        message: "Failed to load blog content",
      })
  }
}
```

```
// +page.svelte

<script>
    import "../../../app.css";
    export let data;
</script>

<div>
    {@html data.post.content}
</div>
```

I can see the `__data.json` generated in the static site output (in `./build`). These are also the errors produced by the console on GitHub Pages:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
...
GET https://ali-mir.com/blog/hello-world/__data.json?x-sveltekit-invalidated=01 404 (Not Found)
```

I had a separate but similar issue with the Tailwind CSS stylesheet not being recognized on GitHub. I had to change the `appDir` to `app` (instead of `__app`) in my `svelte.config.js` file, but I'm not sure if this underscore path issue is related. I'm very new to SvelteKit and front-end in general, so please let me know if anything is unclear!

I already have this set in my `layout.js` file, which I believe generates the `__data.json` file in the static build:

```
export const prerender = true;
export const trailingSlash = 'always';
```

Comment: I have a suspicion this has to do with the fact that I'm using slug-based routing in my project. I was trying to debug this issue and ran into the error `Error: The following routes were marked as prerenderable, but were not prerendered because they were not found while crawling your app:
  - /blog/[slug]`. This makes me think that the `/blog/hello-world/` route i'm trying to produce can't be prerendered, which is why it's not loading initially for my webpage. Does anyone know a workaround? I want to reuse the `.ts` and `+page` files for different blog posts.